# Is there any way know how percentage of the sequence or random IO from the iostat?

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

From the iostat URL below, we know the r/s and w/s, suppose the r/s  is 1000(maybe is composed by 300 sequence IO and 700 random IO) and w/s is 500, however if there is a calculation or way know how many times for the sequence IO  and how many times random IO for the  r/s ,  same question for w/s.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/iostat

Comment: almost all i/o is random, only dd uses sequential. But cfq tries to rearrange them to be closer to sequential. Job of an i/o scheduler is not so trivial. Read more: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/block/cfq-iosched.txt

Comment: Thank you Ipor, it's a great martial.

Answer (score 0):

No - the information given by `iostat` doesn't tell you the sequentiality/randomness of the I/Os passing by. Assuming you can't capture what you're after at a higher level you would have to do something like enable block tracing (via something like `blktrace`) and post process the trace file (e.g. with `btt` or `seekwatcher`).